# underline text when writing a word document using officer package in R

Tags: r, docx, underline, officer

I am trying to create a .docx file in R using officeR package, and I want a piece of text to be underlined. Though [fp_text](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/fp_text.html) offers the arguments to underline text, it does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated!

```
fpt = fp_text(color = "red", bold = TRUE, underlined = TRUE)
fpar_1 <- fpar( ftext("how are you", prop = fpt ), "?")
doc <- read_docx() %>% body_add_fpar(fpar_1)
print(doc, target = "body_add_fpar_1.docx" )
```

Comment: Could you add the expected behavior? What is not working as expected? Could you provide an error message?

Comment: that's a bug! I have just fixed it (on github)

Comment: That explains the issue. Thank you for updating the package @DavidGohel